# How to add the default sound to my push notification in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to add the default sound to my push notification, so far I don't have a sound when I get notification (remote). this my code in `AppDelegate` in Objective-c:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
   [FIRApp configure];
   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"X"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
 rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
 rootViewController.view = rootView;
 self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 return YES;

   }


 // Required to register for notifications
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
 {


    [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

 }
 // Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

  // Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

{
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
     //NSLog(@"push-notification received: %@", notification)   
}
  // Required for the registrationError event.
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
     [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
    // Required for the localNotification event.
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
  }
```

what am I missing? how to set the sound on? I have been working on that many hours and no solution so far...

thank you for the help

**Solution:**
  the problem wasn't in the AppDelegate file like I thought. the file is actually fine. the problem was in the code of the server..
 this is why working code:

```
   Message message = Message.builder()
            .setNotification(new com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification( null,"hihihi"))
                            .setToken(registrationToken).setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder().setAps(Aps.builder().setSound("default").build()).build())
            .build();

    String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

hope it will help to someone

Answer (score 0):

As per I know, you must have a sound parameter in your push notification body.

Comment: "aps" : {
        "alert" : "It's a notification sound!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "notification.wav"
    }

Comment: in notification body, sending from server

Comment: this is my code in the server: 
  Message message = Message.builder()
                .setNotification(new com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification( null,msg))
                .setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();

        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);

Comment: In your server code, notification body is not exist. so thats why it is not working, it is working like -Silent push notification. You must add notification body like you added msg body

Comment: I don't think its possible to add notification body with the class that im working there is no option to do that...

Comment: thank you! after reading more carefully I found the way to fix it in the server...

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification plays default sound when received..
However if you want to change the sound, you should add your sound name in the Payload and sound file to your project..